# I have two harddrives, there's windows 7 installed on the main one, and ubuntu on the other one

Tags: dual-boot

Evening, as the title says I have two HDD, I have windows installed in one and Ubuntu on the other one, both are SATA, After I finished installing ubuntu I restarted my computer, and it instantly booted windows, from the other HDD in order to boot in Ubuntu I had to unplug the other HDD, so.. Is there some kind of a loader of some sort that could help me here and if so, how do I install it, I'm kinda of a noob here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be best to see details. Post just the link the running the Boot Info summary report gives you. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is that it is just automatically looking on the windows disk for an os as it is set to boot from it by default. What you probably need to do to avoid getting into the complexities of chain loading is press f12 (or whatever it is on your computer to change boot devices) and select the name of the ubuntu hard disk when you want to boot into it.

Comment: I guess that's the easy way, thanks man, I'm going to read a little bit about chain loading but.. Later, first I gotta get used to this new world. Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: i've tried chainloading before...not an experience I want to revisit. So long as you have two hard drives pressing f12 is the absolute easiest way I've found so long as you are fine with not everything being seamless. also if I gave you "the answer" feel free to mark it as such :)

Comment: If Grub was installed on the HDD with Ubuntu on it, then hopefully, if you put that HDD higher up in the BIOS boot order, there should be a Grub entry for Windows. If not there are ways to add this entry to Grub.